# JSprit prevent shared shipments

Tags: jsprit

I have multiple shipments to deliver. Each shipment has a type A-Z. A vehicle can hold multiple items, but they must all be the same type. Once the last shipment is dropped off, a vehicle can pick up a shipment of a different type (they just can't be in the vehicle at the same time).

I think I need a `StateUpdater` to update a route with the current shipment type, and a `HardActivityConstraint` or `HardRouteConstraint` to reject the jobs as early as possible, but am not sure how to specifically do this.

Which interfaces should my `StateUpdater` implement?

`StateUpdater, JobInsertedListener, InsertionStartsListener, InsertionEndsListener`?

Which type of constraint do I want to implement in this case?

Comment: Found MultipleProductsWithLoadConstraintExample.java in the examples, and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsprit-mailing-list/2JQqY4loC0U in that file's comments. Might solve this.

Comment: Exactly. The mentioned example should illustrate this.